# Dot Net - XSL Transformation of XML file with special character entity reference

Tags: xml, xslt, special-characters

I got a XML file for which i am applying XSL transformation to get a plain text/CSV file in Dot Net.

The problem is my XML file got special characters like "&amp;"  for "&". When i transform this with XSL i get same  "&amp;" in output as well where i am looking for "&".

I am looking for a option where i can do some XSL transformation of "&amp;" to be converted to "&".

Example : 
XML Source data           :  Adam &amp; Eve 
Ouput as of Now from XSL  :  Adam  & Eve 
Desired Output            :  Adam & Eve

Any Suggestion please?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` for this, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have e.g.

```
<foo>Adam &amp; Eve</foo>
```

in your XML input and your XSLT sets

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

then I am sure the result is `Adam & Eve`. If you get ampersands escaped then you might have the wrong output method.

Comment: Thanks Martin, This would also work for me. In near future i am also looking to transform XML to other formats. Mark's answer would be more suitable in such cases. I'm thankful to your answer also mate :) ta